# Windows 8.0 partition size issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a funny annoying issue with the windows 8.0 installation.

I have a new 1To HDD (not formatted).

I want:

- 100 Go for windows 8.0
- 500 Go NTFS for extend stuff.
- the rest for UNIX systems.

I did partition my HDD when it was plugged on USB with Gparted live USB.

When it's done, still plugged on the USB port, I boot on windows 8 install and here what it's read:

[image: Windows8_USB]

Everything is normal! But windows 8 can not be installed on extern HDD or not like this...

Anyway, I plugged my HDD to my SATA motherboard's port and when I boot on windows 8 here what it's read:

[image]

The partitions size has changed!
This is freaking annoying..

I tried to figured it out and if you look deeper you can see that

> 97.6 GB (byte) = 12.2 Gb (bit) * 8

I guess that windows is misunderstanding my HDD and thinks that my bytes are bits..

Can you tell me where the problem could be from ? Maybe the MBR ?
My knowledge about this stuff is poor.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Ps: If I format with the windows 8 install program, the NTFS partitions aren't recognized on an other windows..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely that your USB enclosure is translating the disk's sector size from 512 bytes to 4096 bytes. This seems to be pretty common these days. The simplest solution is to partition the disk in one way (internally or externally) and use it the same way; don't swap it back and forth. If you *must* swap, you'll probably need to get a new enclosure, although it's possible that yours has a jumper or some other way to disable the sector-size translation.